# How to setup different SSH ports for different Hadoop workers?

Tags: hadoop, ssh, port, worker

I have some Hadoop workers with different SSH ports, so I want to setup different SSH ports for them since Hadoop uses 22 as the default SSH port and although you can change the SSH port of Hadoop AFAIK it applies to all workers. I haven't found any guide on this.

Comment: Changing a port would be done individually, per client/machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself: add hosts' configurations to `~/.ssh/config` and use these configurations as hosts in `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/workers`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting variable:
HADOOP_SSH_OPTS
in
hadoop-env.sh

It should be sth like:

```
export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-p 122"
```

if your new ssh port is 122